# Using Picard-Lindelöf Existence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let A be a square matrix of size $n$, $f : \mathbb R_+→\mathbb R^n$
continuous, $x_o∈\mathbb R^n$.

(a) Using the global Picard-Lindelöf Existence Theorem, show that there
exists a unique solution to the initial value problem $x'=Ax + f(t), t ≥ 0,
x(0) = x_o$.

(b) Show that

$$x(t) = e^{tA}(x_o+\int_0^t{e^{-sA}f(s)ds}$$

is a solution of the initial value problem $x'=Ax+f(t),t≥0,x(0)=x_o$.

(c) For the solution $x$ in (b) show that

$$x(t)=e^{tA}x_o+\int_0^t{e^{(t-s)A}f(s)ds}.$$

Picard-Lindelöf Existence Theorem:

Let $I$ be a nondegenerate interval and $f : I × \mathbb R^n →\mathbb R^n$ be *continuous* and *Lipschitz continuous* in the state
variable. Then, for $t_o \in I$ and $x_o ∈ \mathbb R^n$, there exists a solution $x : I → \mathbb R^n$ of
$x' = f(t, x),  x(t_o) = x_o$. This solution is unique.

Comment: You need to show your attempts of solution and the experienced difficulties/issues.

Comment: I just don't understand how to attack this proof. Everything I wrote down on my paper was nonsense and didn't get me anything. The matrix throws me off as well. Is $f(x)$ supposed to be a matrix too? Isn't dimension of $A$=n²?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The most important point is to check the Lipschitz condition for $F(t,x)=Ax+f(t)$. Now linearity makes this very easy, $$\|F(t,x_1)-F(t,x_2)\|=\|A(x_1-x_2)\|\le\|A\|\,\|x_1-x_2\|.$$

b) Use $e^{-tA}$ as integrating factor.

c) This is just a re-formulation of b). Perhaps you need to point out that $-sA$ commutes with $tA$.